# Can't register the interrupt by linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, interrupt

I have a soc board and want to register a fpga fabric interrupt on my hps board.
The following is my kernel module code:

```
    ret = request_any_context_irq(TIMER_IRQ_NUM,FPGA_timer_irq_handler,IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING|IRQF_SHARED,"timer_irq",&timer_50us);
    if(ret<0)
    {
        pr_info("ERROR: request_irq failed error return %d\n",ret);
        goto fail_request_irq;
    }
```

The hanlder code is:

```
/*handler*/
static irqreturn_t FPGA_timer_irq_handler(int irq,void* dev_id)
{
    //check the irq num 
    if(irq!=TIMER_IRQ_NUM)
        return IRQ_NONE;
    
    //lock sequence
    spin_lock(&interrupt_flag_lock);
    interrupt_flag = 1;                         
    input_state = ioread16(timer_state_mem);     
    spin_unlock(&interrupt_flag_lock);

    wake_up_interruptible(&interrupt_wq);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

The dev_id struct is:

```
struct timer_irq_struct
{
     unsigned int irq_num;
     void* pData;
};
struct timer_irq_struct timer_50us={TIMER_IRQ_NUM,NULL};
```

I got the return value -22 which my parameter is wrong.

Any ideas on fixing that?

Comment: Yes, you should get the difference between _Linux kernel interrupt_ number space and _hardware IRQ_.  Moreover, your FPGA most likely is a PCIe device, its interrupt number has to be used (which is retrieved via `pci_irq_vector()`, but don't forget to allocate it first).